# Python class inheritance: how is this output produced?

Tags: python, class, oop, object, inheritance

When I run this code it is giving output as 10 10 10 12 24 10. Can anyone please help me in understanding the output? I am new to python programming

```
class A:
    x = 10

class B(A):
    pass

class C(A):
    pass

print (A.x)

print (B.x)

print (C.x)

A.x += 2

B.x *= 2

C.x -= 2

print (A.x)

print (B.x)

print (C.x)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Unfortunately [questions asking for: books, libraries, tutorials, tools are off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and should be closed. Stack Overflow is a [Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) & [Answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) website for specific programming questions.

Comment: Can you demonstrate *any* effort at solving this yourself?

Comment: Why do you need to use the `class` and not the `def` (function) in the Python code ? Why just `class` ? Why do you need explaination of the example code ? Your code, I think, demonstrates the inheritance of a class from another base class: `class main_class(base_class):` But the best would be a Python textbook or a manual: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html

Comment: I think that this is an very interesting question. B.x*=2 creates a new object. Before it was just a reference to A.x. Amd then C.x still references A.x therefore you get 10 at the end.
Please update the title and add a description of your concrete problem (what would you expect and what differs from your expectations).
If you do so, I will take back my down vote.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which programming languages you know, but Python works different here, than other languages. In C++ you would just assume that the variable x exists 3 times as own instances, which means that the variables are independent from each other. This would lead to the output sequence 10 10 10 12 20 8.

However, I think that for Python, the following happens here:

- You create class A with a variable x = 10. When creating class B and C, then they don't instantiate an own variable x. Instead B and C have a "reference" to A.x. That's why you get 10 10 10 at first.
- You change A.x += 2, so x = 12 now. When you change B.x *= 2, then the following assignment is made to B.x: B.x = A.x * 2. From this moment on, B.x is an own variable, independent from A.x. Same happens for C.x -= 2. That leads to you to the sequence 12 24 10.

I think that for Python you need to know the concept "call by object", which is omnipresent. It is different than known concepts as "call by value" or "call by reference". See also [Is Python call by reference or value](https://jeffknupp.com/blog/2012/11/13/is-python-callbyvalue-or-callbyreference-neither/).